# Make frame in same location independent

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below userform and I would like to be able to show `frame1` or `frame2` as if they were independent.
So far, my first button `show frame1` works well, **but not the second one.**

Any advice ?

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Frame1.Visible = True
Frame2.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Frame1.Visible = False
Frame2.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This happens because Frame2 is embed in Frame1, it's part of it. So when you hide frame1 it also hides frame 2.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, is it possible to make frame2 independent from frame1 ?

Comment: Nope, in all MS Office products when you drop a frame in another frame, they are automatically bound. The solution to circumvent this in MS Access, is to use 2 rectangle shapes instead of Frames, you make their interior transparent and then you can manipulate them independently. But UserForms in Excel are very basic and don't have any shape control. It's probably possible to achieve this with a drawing API and VBA, but that will be long and hard

Comment: Your best bet is to move `Frame2` out of `Frame1` and along with setting the visibility of each when the buttons are pressed, set the `.Left` and `.Top` properties to place them where you want them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, the following would do what you're after - provided in normal edit mode the two frames are not within one or the other like so:

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Frame1.Visible = True
    Frame1.Left = 12
    Frame1.Top = 12
    Frame2.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Frame2.Visible = True
    Frame2.Left = 36
    Frame2.Top = 36
    Frame1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Just adjust the `12` and `36` values to your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Sub myFrame()
Dim c as control
For each c in me.controls
If typename(c)="Frame" then
With c
.height=40
.width=40
.left=0
.top=0
End with
End if
Next c
End sub

sub Cmd1_click()
Frame2.visible=false
With Frame1
.visible=true
.zorder msobringtofront
End with
End sub

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).